# Adding host without www not working with Ingress resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a couple of questions

1. When we make changes to ingress resource, are there any cases where we have to delete the resource and re-create it again or is `kubectl apply -f <file_name>` sufficient?
2. When I add the host attribute without `www i.e. (my-domain.in)`, I am not able to access my application but with `www i.e. (www.my-domain.in)` it works, what's the difference?

Below is my ingress resource

When I have the host set to `my-domain.in`, I am unable to access my application, but when i set the host to `www.my-domain.in` I can access the application.

my domain is on a different provider and I have added CNAME (www) pointing to DNS name of my ALB.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: eks-learning-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:a982529496:cerd878ef678df
  labels:
    app: eks-learning-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.in **does not work**
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          backend:
            serviceName: eks-learning-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: You don't have to delete Ingress objects to update it, the `kubectl apply` is the recommended format. Either it will show `ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress unchanged` or `ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress configured`. this Ingress you posted, is the working one? Please explain the desired state so we can troubleshoot the syntax and rule.

Comment: hi @willrof,  the issue is that in the host if i don't specify `www`, like you see in the file above, my application does not load. But when i add `www` to the host it works. I will update my question, sorry for not being clear

Comment: @willrof, just updated the question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for enhancing the question. I believe it's a DNS question. There is a way you can test that, from kubernetes outwards. I'll post all my troubleshooting suggestion as an answer since a domain problem is ayways a case-by-case scenario.

Comment: thanks @willrof, look forward to it

Comment: one last question, how many services do you have exposed in your kubernetes? because if ALL you need is to define a default route for the requests there are easier ways to do this. I believe you have a lot of services and that you redacted them from the ingress and your problem is only with the default backend?

Comment: just have one `NodePort` type service

Comment: Do you mind posting the output of `kubectl get svc`? If I'm correct you really don't need to worry about domain rules, just a default rule without hostname would suffice.

Comment: eks-learning-service   NodePort    1.10.13.12   <none>        80:32436/TCP   22h
redis                  ClusterIP   1.10.7.4     <none>        6379/TCP       42m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208590/discussion-between-willrof-and-opensource-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First answering your question 1:

  > When we make changes to ingress resource, are there any cases where we have to delete the resource and re-create it again or is kubectl apply -f  sufficient?

**In theory, yes, the `kubectl apply` is the correct way**, either it will show `ingress unchanged` or `ingress configured`.

Other valid [documented](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#updating-an-ingress) option is `kubectl edit ingress INGRESS_NAME` which saves and apply at the end of the edition if the output is valid.

*I said theory because bugs happen, so we can't fully discard it, but bug is the worst case scenario.*

- Now the blurrier question 2:

  > When I add the host attribute without www i.e. (my-domain.in), I am not able to access my application but with www i.e. (www.my-domain.in) it works, what's the difference?

To troubleshoot it we need to isolate the processes, like in a chain we have to find which link is broken. One by one:

***Endpoint > Domain Provider> Cloud Provider > Ingress > Service > Pod.***

1. DNS Resolution (Domain Provider)
2. DNS Resolution (Cloud Provider)
3. Kubernetes Ingress (Ingress > Service > Pod)

---

### DNS Resolution

---

**Domain Provider:**

To the Internet, who answers for `my-domain.in` is your Domain Provider.

- What are the rules for `my-domain.in` and it's subdomains (like `www.my-domain.in` or `admin.my-domain.in`)?
  You said *"domain is on a different provider and I have added CNAME (www) pointing to DNS name of my ALB."*

  - Are `my-domain.in` and `my-domain.in` being redirected to the ALB address instinctively?
  - How does it handle URL subdomains? how the request is passed on to your Cloud?

**Cloud Provider:**

Ok, the cloud provider is receiving the request correctly and distinctly.

- Does your ALB have generic or specific rules for subdomains or path requests?
- Test with another host, a different VM with a web server.
- [Check  ALB Troubleshooting Page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html)

### Kubernetes Ingress

Usually we would start the troubleshoot from this part, but since you mentioned it works with `www.my-domain.in`, we can presume that your service, deployment and even ingress structure is working correctly.

You can check the [Types of Ingress Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress) to get a few examples of how it should work.

**Bottom Line:** I believe  your DNS has a route for  `www.my-domain.in` but the root domain has no route to your cloud provider that's why it's only working when you are enabling the ingress for www.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am using godaddy as a domain host and they don't have a way to add bare domain as a CNAME record. I found that when I added a redirect rule for my-domain.in to be redirected to https under my `ALB`, i was able to access the application. The reason i used CNAME is because ALB does not provide a IP, if not i could have used `A` record instead of CNAME.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get a `Static IP` for my `ALB`. I will mark it as accepted answer as it points out where the issue actually is, but it would be great to understand why without redirect rule i was not event seeing the application(server not found) error

Comment: i had to add 2 comments because it would not let me all all at once, sorry for that